# Using GNU Octave GLPK to solve an Optimization Problem that has an Absolute Value in the Objective Function

Tags: optimization, octave, linear-programming

I want to minimize:

|0.2126 * R1 + 0.7152 * G1 + 0.0722 * B1 - 7(0.2126 * R2 + 0.7152 * G2 + 0.0722 * B2) - (7-1) * 0.05|

subject to the constraint:

0.2126 * R1 + 0.7152 * G1 + 0.0722 * B1 - (0.2126 * R2 + 0.7152 * G2 + 0.0722 * B2) >= 0

This is my code so far

```
ratio = 7;

objective_coefficients  = [ 0.2126,  0.7152,  0.0722, ratio * -0.2126, ratio * -0.7152, ratio * -0.0722, (1 - ratio) * 0.05]';
constraint_coefficients = [ 0.2126,  0.7152,  0.0722,         -0.2126,         -0.7152,         -0.0722];
constraint_right_hand_side_values = [0]';
variable_lower_bounds = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]';
variable_upper_bounds = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
constriant_types = "L";
variable_types = "CCCCCCC";
sense = 1;

parameters.messsage_level = 1;
parameters.iterations_limit = 100;

[xmin, fmin, status, extra] = glpk(objective_coefficients,
                                   constraint_coefficients,
                                   constraint_right_hand_side_values,
                                   variable_lower_bounds,
                                   variable_upper_bounds,
                                   constriant_types,
                                   variable_types,
                                   sense,
                                   parameters);
```

The result xmin are all 1s.

Comment: Why is the last variable fixed at 1?

Comment: @Reinderien There's only 6 variables: R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, and B2. The last one represents the constant -0.36 in the objective function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In practical terms, demonstrating with a similar-smelling `scipy.optimize.linprog`, you need an objective auxiliary variable that's minimized with coefficient 1, having 0 for all other objective coefficients. Add constraint rows so that the objective auxiliary is greater than both the absolute argument and the absolute negative argument; this leaves you with

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

ratio = 7

objective_coefficients = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
constraint_coefficients = np.array([
    [-0.2126, -0.7152, -0.0722,        0.2126,         0.7152,        0.0722,  0],  # -ax <= 0
    [ 0.2126,  0.7152,  0.0722, -ratio*0.2126, -ratio *0.7152, -ratio*0.0722, -1],  #  bx + c <= obj :  bx - obj <= -c
    [-0.2126, -0.7152, -0.0722,  ratio*0.2126,  ratio *0.7152,  ratio*0.0722, -1],  # -bx - c <= obj : -bx - obj <=  c
])
constraint_right_hand_side_values = np.array([
    0,
     ratio*0.05 + 0.36,
    -ratio*0.05 - 0.36,
])
variable_lower_bounds = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,      0]
variable_upper_bounds = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, np.inf]

result = linprog(
    c=objective_coefficients,
    bounds=np.array((variable_lower_bounds, variable_upper_bounds)).T,
    A_ub=constraint_coefficients,
    b_ub=constraint_right_hand_side_values,
)

R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2, obj = result.x
print(result)
print()

print('Confirmation:')
print(0.2126*R1 + 0.7152*G1 + 0.0722 - (0.2126*R2 + 0.7152*G2 + 0.0722*B2), '>= 0')
obj_lhs = result.x[:-1] @ [
    0.2126,  0.7152,  0.0722, ratio*-0.2126, ratio*-0.7152, ratio*-0.0722
] - (ratio*0.05 + 0.36)
print(f'|{obj_lhs}| <= {obj}')
print()
```

```
        message: Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
        success: True
         status: 0
            fun: 0.0
              x: [ 0.000e+00  8.918e-01  1.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
                   0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
            nit: 1
          lower:  residual: [ 0.000e+00  8.918e-01  1.000e+00  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00  0.000e+00  1.000e+00]
          upper:  residual: [ 1.000e+00  1.082e-01  0.000e+00  1.000e+00
                              1.000e+00  1.000e+00        inf]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
          eqlin:  residual: []
                 marginals: []
        ineqlin:  residual: [ 7.100e-01  0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [-0.000e+00 -0.000e+00 -0.000e+00]
 mip_node_count: 0
 mip_dual_bound: 0.0
        mip_gap: 0.0

Confirmation:
0.71 >= 0
|0.0| <= 0.0
```

In other words, it's quite possible for your objective to be "perfect" (equal to 0), which means that (using your new definition of the objective function) you can simplify the problem to

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

ratio = 7
coeffs = np.outer([-1, 1], [0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722])
result = linprog(
    c=np.zeros(6),
    bounds=np.array((np.zeros(6), np.ones(6))).T,
    A_ub=                 coeffs.reshape((1, -1)), b_ub=[0],
    A_eq=(([1], [ratio])*coeffs).reshape((1, -1)), b_eq=[(1 - ratio)*0.05])
R1, G1, B1, R2, G2, B2 = result.x
print(result)
print()

print('Confirmation:')
print(0.2126*R1 + 0.7152*G1 + 0.0722*B1 - (0.2126*R2 + 0.7152*G2 + 0.0722*B2), '>= 0')
obj_lhs = result.x @ [
    0.2126,  0.7152,  0.0722, ratio*-0.2126, ratio*-0.7152, ratio*-0.0722,
] - (ratio - 1)*0.05
print(obj_lhs, '== 0')
```

```
        message: Optimization terminated successfully. (HiGHS Status 7: Optimal)
        success: True
         status: 0
            fun: 0.0
              x: [ 1.000e+00  2.125e-02  1.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
                   0.000e+00]
            nit: 0
          lower:  residual: [ 1.000e+00  2.125e-02  1.000e+00  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
          upper:  residual: [ 0.000e+00  9.787e-01  0.000e+00  1.000e+00
                              1.000e+00  1.000e+00]
                 marginals: [ 0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00  0.000e+00
                              0.000e+00  0.000e+00]
          eqlin:  residual: [ 0.000e+00]
                 marginals: [-0.000e+00]
        ineqlin:  residual: [ 3.000e-01]
                 marginals: [-0.000e+00]
 mip_node_count: 0
 mip_dual_bound: 0.0
        mip_gap: 0.0

Confirmation:
0.30000000000000004 >= 0
0.0 == 0
```

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question with example implementation that I can easily convert to Octave code. I'll wait till I accept your answer

Comment: Hello! I noticed this line: constraint_right_hand_side_values = np.array([ 0, ratio*0.05 + 0.36, -ratio*0.05 - 0.36, ]) was wrong, and should be constraint_right_hand_side_values = np.array([ 0, (ratio-1) * 0.05, (1-ratio) * 0.05 ]) Even so, the pair it gave doesn't minimize the objective function. It gave (1, 0.021253, 1, 0, 0, 0) for ratio = 7. If you plug those into the objective function, the result is 2.41637790822*10^-5. I have a better answer: (0.063010, 0.863157, 0.283149, 0.009134, 0.061246, 0.061246). If you plug those into the objective function, the result is 7.7715611724*10^−15

Comment: @Aphrontos See edit. Even with your modified objective function definition, the objective can still equal zero, so use the second method I showed.

Comment: I understand now. I made an error in my formulation, since this isn't the result I expected. Still, thank you, I will accept your answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
min abs(x)
```

can be formulated as:

```
min y
    -y ≤ x ≤ y   (usually: split into two constraints)
    y ≥ 0
```

or using variable splitting

```
 min  xplus+xmin
      xplus-xmin=x
      xplus,xmin ≥ 0
```

For the details see any textbook on linear programming.